# Using Picture-in-picture feature with Android O

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view, android-window, android-picture-in-picture

I have created an android app to check the feature Picture In Picture mode of Android O.
But i facing an error while running this application.

setPictureInPictureArgs: Device doesn't support picture-in-picture mode

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: setPictureInPictureArgs: Device doesn't support picture-in-picture mode.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1923)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1861)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setPictureInPictureArgs(IActivityManager.java:9378)
       at android.app.Activity.setPictureInPictureArgs(Activity.java:1984)
       at com.example.pip.MainActivity.updatePictureInPictureActions(MainActivity.java:156)
       at com.example.pip.MainActivity$2.onMovieStarted(MainActivity.java:101)
       at com.example.pip.widget.MovieView.play(MovieView.java:350)
       at com.example.pip.widget.MovieView$3.onPrepared(MovieView.java:384)
       at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:3170)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6440)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:746)
```

Comment: What are you running this on?

Comment: Your device isn't running Android O, so is throwing this exception as PiP isn't supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is no longer reproducible in the stable version of Android O.

Comment: I got the same error for android 8.1 so I don't think that it is an OS-level bug.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes devices running on Android-O and above but unable to run PIP because it is disabled by the device due to low RAM size.

So, before your app uses PIP, it is better to check feature is available or not by calling `hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE)`.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE)) {
            //your code
        }
    }
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture#best